# Google Apps Script add-ons: Installable trigger limitations

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-apps-script-addon

I'm looking to build an add-on that allows the user to backup data from a third-party API.

The idea is that the user submits a sidebar form with some parameters required for the API, then the add-on creates a time-driven trigger that retrieves the data and outputs it to a user-specified spreadsheet.

The developer docs mention "Each add-on can only have one trigger of each type, per user, per document.". I'm curious to know if a user can add multiple "backup" triggers via the same add-on, as long as each trigger outputs data to a unique spreadsheet.

For example, the user installs the add-on in Spreadsheet A. He/She creates a backup trigger which outputs data in Spreadsheet B, then creates another backup trigger (such as one with different parameters) which outputs data in Spreadsheet C. Spreadsheet B and C do not have the add-on installed.

Is the scenario in the example possible? Or does the user need to install the add-on for each spreadsheet in order to have multiple backup triggers active?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this right, these are 3 different spreadsheets and not 3 different sheets within the same one. Also, since you mentioned that the data being backed up from B to C has different parameters than the data being passed from A to B, you will need to install the trigger on both A and B. And since no data is being passed on from C, you don't require the add-on for a backup trigger there. Reason being that a trigger installed on A will not be able to access data on B, filter it according to a different set of parameters and pass it on to C. Hence, B will require to have the add-on to set-up a separate trigger altogether. Hope this helps!

Comment: I ended up making it so that each trigger is bound to the spreadsheet where the user activates the backup. The spreadsheet ID is saved to the DocumentProperties, which the trigger can access when it runs.

Comment: @MihaiA - I am in similar situation and wanted to ask if you can share some insights.

-- I have 2 columns in my Google sheet spreadsheet, lets call them Column A and B.

-- I have two functions in my apps script, where first function fetches data from an API and output that in Column A, whereas second function compare that data with existing data in Column B and send an email if differences detected.

-- I tried adding 2 triggers in my add ons and tested it with my another account, but get error saying too many add ons.

Any help is appreciated.